# How to merge duplicated cells in bulk per each column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Need to merge data per column if records in the first column are the same.

I wrote a VBA code and it works but it works very slow as it executes "merge" function per each row no matter if consequent cells are the same or different.

```
Sub DuplicateValues()

'Declare All Variables:

Dim myCell As Range
Dim myRow As Integer
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myFirstColumn As Long

Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range

'Count Number of Rows and Columns:

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

myRow = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown)).Count + 2 'first two rows are headers
myCol = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count

'Apply formatting to the end of the table:

With ActiveSheet
Set rngCopy = .Range(.Range("A3"), .Cells(myRow, myCol))

 With rngCopy.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With

'Merge duplicated cells per Row:

myFirstRow = 3
myFirstColumn = 1

Set iRow = Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn)
Set n = Cells(myFirstRow + 1, myFirstColumn)

For i = 1 To myRow

    If iRow <> n Then

                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 8), Cells(myFirstRow, 8)).WrapText = True
                Range(Cells(myFirstRow, 1), Cells(myFirstRow, myCol - 3)).EntireRow.AutoFit       

                iRow = Cells(myFirstRow + i, myFirstColumn)
                n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)

                Else
                n = Cells(myFirstRow + i + 1, myFirstColumn)

                    For k = 1 To myCol - 3 'need to merge data per column but don't need to merge data in the last 3 columns

                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).Merge
                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, 8), Cells(myFirstRow + i, 8)).WrapText = True
                        Range(Cells(myFirstRow + i - 1, k), Cells(myFirstRow + i, k)).EntireRow.AutoFit

                    Next

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I tried to create a different logic to initiate "merge" by blocks (skip merging the same value cells in the first column right away):
merging only when the "base/initial" cell is not the same as a "check" cell and merge all appropriate cells all together (not by each row), but I can't find a way to make it work.

Would be very grateful for any code optimizations!

Comment: If your code works, then this question may be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: code doesn't really work as I would want it to..